# (git) 歴史 A..B の間が一本鎖であることを判定するには？

Tags: git

コミットA,B があって A は B の祖先だとします。
A -> B への間の歴史が、一本鎖であることを判定するには、どうしたらいいでしょうか。

より正確に記述するならば、
A..B の間のコミットがすべて、マージコミットでないことを判定するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git log --merges A..B` でマージコミットだけ表示されます

Comment: (( !$(git log COMMIT_A..COMMIT_B --merges --format=format:%H | wc -w) ))

で、判定できました。